# Sorry, [almost everything] has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: root-access, factory-reset, usb-debugging, bugs

when starting one of my rooted Z740 AT&T phones, it, after about 30 seconds, starts by stopping Google play services, then after about 5 consecutive of those most apps start crashing and the only way to open any app is using iSwipe from Clean Master.

I cannot to a reset as in the way through the settings won't do anything, and my volume keys are broken.

any Idea to suppress the notifications, or better, reset the device is greatly appreciated.

Usb debugging has been enabled before hand and works fine

Comment: Both the volume up and down are broken ?

Comment: @esQmo yes, i had gotten 2, both nonfunctional z740s, swapped batteries, one worked the other (the one mentioned) needed taken apart and in the process of it, little ribbon that was soldered on the motherboard broke, mid way. I haven't soldered before and all my friends that have are busy.

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Comment: @wbogacz for me, Clean Master was very helpful, as it's 'iSwipe' was the only thing that allowed me to open ANY app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, wasn't easy and i'm probably only 1 of 2 people it has happened to (his solution didn't work for me.)

The /data partition was RO locked while in Android.

After installing the touch version of CWM, I mounted the data partition

In an ADB shell I did `mount -o remount,rw,errors=continue -t ect4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata` to mount it as RW, it worked

after that since I finally got it RW, I then did a format of it through CWM

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending an Intent with the adb shell. Connect the device, open a terminal and type the following :

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MASTER_CLEAR
```

You need adb installed.

Comment: just while booted into android?

Comment: Yes, since the USB debugging is enabled, this should work fine.

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow, I left it at my work and I need to reassemble it

Comment: sorry, just left it at home, I'll do it as soon as I can

Comment: how long should it take for the phone to take the intent that was sent?

Comment: It's been about 2 minutes and my phone has done nothing  and it seems the request is still being sent.

Comment: Does adb detect your phone? What is the output of `adb devices` ?

Comment: P823A01 device is the only device attached, witch is my phone, I also can't uninstall apps currently too

Comment: try adb shell then wipe_data or wipe data

Comment: after doin `wipe data` i get `Wiping /data
Error opendir'ing /data 'Permission denied'
Done wiping /data`

Comment: why don't I have permission, I can't do adb root as it's still using a production build

Comment: As you have root access, try adb shell then su then wipe data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51729/discussion-between-danholli-and-esqmo).

Comment: Root access is gained using the `su` command on  production builds.

Comment: I just found out the partition is read-only, but the normal mount command can't remount it as read-write

Comment: It needs root to mount as rw.

Comment: it wouldn't while booted with `su` or not, I fixed it by doing what I gave in my answer

Comment: Okay, didn't see the answer. Hlad that it worked.